# Is there any better way to get data between days in H2 Database?

Tags: h2

We want to select data from table with below condition.

`Date of Transactiontime <= (Current Date - n Days)`

for e.g.

1. Today is - 2016-06-21.
2. Date of Transactiontime = '2016-06-19 11:45:07.148'.
3. With below query we could get **Data which is 2 days** older.

**Query:**

`SELECT * FROM T WHERE FORMATDATETIME (Transactiontime,'YYYY-MM-d') <= FORMATDATETIME ( DATEADD('HH',-2*24,Now()), 'YYYY-MM-d');`

`Dataype of Transactiontime = TIMESTAMP`

Is there any better way to get the same results?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried function [`DATEDIFF()`](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#datediff)?

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE DATEDIFF('DAY', NOW(), Transactiontime) >= 2
```

### EDIT

Might be better using `DAY_OF_YEAR` instead of `DAY`.